# Puppeter delete node inside element

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to scrape a page with some news inside.
Here it's an HTML simplified version of what I have :

```
<info id="random_number" class="news"> 
    <div class="author">
        Name of author  
    </div>
    <div class="news-body">
        <blockquote>...<blockquote>
        Here it's the news text
    </div>
</info>
<info id="random_number" class="news"> 
    <div class="author">
        Name of author  
    </div>
    <div class="news-body">
        Here it's the news text
    </div>
</info>
```

I want to get the author and text body of each news, without the blockquote part.
So I wrote this code :

```
let newsPage = await newsPage.$$("info.news");
for (var news of newsPage){ // Loop through each element
      let author = await news.$eval('.author', s => s.textContent.trim());
      let textBody = await news.$eval('.news-body', s => s.textContent.trim());
      console.log('Author :'+ author);
      console.log('TextBody :'+ textBody);
}
```

It works well, but I don't know how to remove the blockquote part of the "news-body" part, before getting the text, how can I do this ?

EDIT : Sometimes there is blockquote exist, sometime not.

Comment: maybe replace `s => s.textContent.trim()` with `{ s.querySelector('blockquote').remove(); s.textContent.trim() }` ?

Comment: It works great but I forget to say that sometimes there is no blockquote. I can handle a if here ?

Comment: You can use optional chaining: `s.querySelector('blockquote')?.remove();`.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried : let textMessage = await comment.$eval('.news-body', s => { s.querySelector('blockquote')?.remove(); s.textContent.trim() });
But I get undefined when I do : console.log('TextMessage :'+ textMessage);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). Also you may consider  [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) more readable.

```js
let textMessage = await comment.$eval('.news-body', (element) => { 
  element.querySelector('blockquote')?.remove();
  return element.innerText.trim();
});
```